# How to get this code to behave differently based on what exactly is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, I apologize if this code is kind of chaotic. I have tried trimming it down significantly. http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/7hLrLdn2/14/

I wrote comments in the JS code showing the relevant areas I'm referring to for this question. Please see "Relevant Section" and "Other Relevant Section".

Basically, when you type into the input box and hit enter, a list item appears. On the list item, you can click the 'X' to delete that list item. However, there is also an 'O' button on the left. I would like it to have a different function than the X button.

However, the code basically says "take anything wrapped in an 'a' tag and, when clicking that, delete the list item", so what I would like to be able to do is differentiate the two in the code. The only thing I have found that works is wrapping O in a random 'd' tag instead (I don't even know what that is) and changing the code appropriately, but obviously that just seems like nonsensical code and bad practice.

How do I get clicking 'O' to be a different function than clicking 'X' on a list item?

HTML

```
  <body>
       <div class="UpCenter">             
                <div id="navbarcontainer">        
                    <ul class="navbar cf">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="ActiveListItem">Music</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Movie</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Book</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="lister" id="interestboxcontainer">
                    <form action="">
                        <input type="text" class="clearable" placeholder="type here" autocomplete="off">
                    </form>
                </div>


            </div>



                <div id="DownCenter">



                <div id="LeftPanel"> 

                    <div id="MusicDiv" class="UserCategories">
                        Your Music
                        <div class="lister">
                            <ul class="active" style="min-width:365px;">
                                <!--
                                <li>1<a href="">X</a></li>
                                -->
                            </ul>
                        </div>       
                    </div>

                    <div id="MovieDiv" class="UserCategories">
                         Your Movies
                         <div class="lister">
                            <ul class="active" style="min-width:365px;">
                                <!--
                                <li>1<a href="">X</a></li>
                                -->
                            </ul>
                         </div>     
                    </div>                

                    <div id="BookDiv" class="UserCategories">
                         Your Books
                         <div class="lister">
                            <ul class="active" style="min-width:365px;">
                                <!--
                                <li>1<a href="">X</a></li>
                                -->
                            </ul>
                         </div>               
                    </div>





                </div> 






                <div id="RightPanel"> 
                    <div id="SideBarSearchDiv">

                    </div>

                    <div id="SearchDiv">                    
                        <div id="GenreMusicDiv" class="GenreCategories">
                            Genre
                            <div class="GenreMusicList">
                                Bands
                            </div>    
                        </div>

                        <div id="GenreMovieDiv" class="GenreCategories">
                            Genre
                            <div class="GenreMovieList">
                                Movies
                            </div>                       
                        </div>

                        <div id="GenreBookDiv" class="GenreCategories">
                            Genre
                            <div class="GenreBookList">
                                Books
                            </div>                       
                        </div>

                    </div>       
                </div>
           </div>

       </div>
```

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400, 300, 600);


* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


html {
 background:#1e1e1e;                                
}


body {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}



#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width:1500px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    position:relative; 
}


#navbarcontainer{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;   
}

#interestboxcontainer{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
}



.UpCenter{
    padding-top:30px;
    height:90px;
}


#DownCenter{
    color:white;
    width:1120px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:none;
}


#LeftPanel{                        /*Left Panel*/
    position:absolute;
    vertical-align:top;  
    margin-bottom:50px;
    height:600px; 
    background-color:#343434;
    width:365px;
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:12px;
    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
}

#RightPanel{
    vertical-align:top;

    height:100%;
}

#SearchDiv{                        /*Right Panel*/
    background-color:#343434;
    width:365px;
    height:600px;
    margin-bottom:50px; 
    margin-left:389px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:12px;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-left-color:#484848;
    border-top-right-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;

}


.UserCategories{
    display:none;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    background:red;
}

#MusicDiv{

}

#MovieDiv{

}

#BookDiv{

}



.GenreCategories{
    display:none;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    background:orange;
}

#GenreMusicDiv{

}

#GenreMovieDiv{ 

}

#GenreBookDiv{   

}



/* navbar */
ul.navbar {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px; 
  border-color:#739FE0;
  width: 100px;                
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size:14px;
  height:33px;
}

ul.navbar li a.ActiveListItem {
    background:url(../images/downarrowblue.png) !important; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 10px 10px !important;
    background-position: 83px 13px !important;
    color:white; !important;
    background-color:#222 !important;
    padding:7.5px 0px !important; 
    font-weight:normal !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height:18px;
    width:100px;   
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

ul.navbar li {    
    z-index:100;
    position: relative;
    width:100px;                        
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding:10px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover,
ul.navbar li:hover > a {
    background:#739FE0;
    color:pink;  
}

ul.navbar li ul {
        margin-top: 0px;               
        background: #222;
        font-size: 14px;
        display: none;
        z-index: 50;

}

ol, ul { list-style: outside none none; }

.hidden { display: none; }


/*Lister*/
form {  }

.lister input {
    width:235px;   
    height:33px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
    background-color:#222;
    color:white;
}

.lister input:focus {
    outline:none;
}

.lister ul {
    background:none;
    font-family:"Tahoma";
}

.active { 
    text-align:center;
}                                       

.inactive { display: none;}

.lister li {    
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #000000;   
    display:inline-block; 
    padding:3px; 
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

.lister li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: blue;           
    border-color:#ccc;
    color:#ccc;    
}

.lister li:nth-child(even) {
    background: blue;           
    border-color:#ccc;
    color:#ccc;
}

.lister li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.lister li > a:hover {
    /*font-size: 105%;*/
    /*color: #c0392b;*/
    color:#000000;

}

.lister li > span {
    display:inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width:379px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {

    var container = $('.navbar');


  $('.navbar ul li a').click(function(){  
    $('.navbar > li:first-child > a').text($(this).text());
    $('.navbar > li > ul').addClass('hidden');
    $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(100);
  });
  $('.navbar > li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').removeClass('hidden');
  });
  $('.ActiveListItem').click(function(){        
    $('.navbar li ul').slideToggle(300);
  });


 $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $('.navbar li ul').slideUp(300);
    }
     });
});





$(document).ready(function() {

    function setMusicHeight(){  
        $('#GenreMusicDiv').outerHeight($('#MusicDiv').outerHeight());         
    }

    function setMovieHeight(){     
        $('#GenreMovieDiv').outerHeight($('#MovieDiv').outerHeight()); 
    }

    function setBookHeight(){ 
        $('#GenreBookDiv').outerHeight($('#BookDiv').outerHeight());    
    }


    var ul = $('.lister ul'),
        input = $('input');

    $('form').submit(function () {           
            setMusicHeight();                 
            setMovieHeight();
            setBookHeight();


        if (input.val() !== '') {

            var inputVal = input.val(),
                activeNumber = $('.ActiveListItem').text();



            if (activeNumber == "Music") {

                $('#MusicDiv').fadeIn();
                $('#GenreMusicDiv').fadeIn();
                ul = $('#MusicDiv ul');

            } else if (activeNumber == "Movie") {

                $('#MovieDiv').fadeIn();
                $('#GenreMovieDiv').fadeIn();
                ul = $('#MovieDiv ul');

            } else if (activeNumber == "Book") {
                $('#BookDiv').fadeIn();
                $('#GenreBookDiv').fadeIn();
                ul = $('#BookDiv ul');

            } else {
                ul = $('#NonExistent ul');

            }


            /*Relevant Section*/     
             $('<li>' + '<a>' + 'O' + '</a>' + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + '<span>' + inputVal + '</span>' + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + '<a>' + 'X' + '</a></li>').hide().appendTo(ul).slideToggle(270);


            if (ul.hasClass('inactive')) {
                ul.removeClass('inactive')
                    .addClass('active');
            }

        };


        input.val('');   
        return false;

    });


    /*Other Relevant Section*/
    ul.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().slideUp('fast', function() {
            if ($('#MusicDiv').height() < 85) {
                $('#MusicDiv').fadeOut(275);
                $('#GenreMusicDiv').fadeOut(275); 
            } 

            if ($('#MovieDiv').height() < 85) {
                $('#MovieDiv').fadeOut(275);
                $('#GenreMovieDiv').fadeOut(275);
            } 

            if ($('#BookDiv').height() < 85) {
                $('#BookDiv').fadeOut(275);
                $('#GenreBookDiv').fadeOut(275);
            } 
        });


        if (ul.children().length == 0) {
            ul.removeClass('active')
                .addClass('inactive');
            input.focus();            
        }

    });

        $(".navbar.cf li ul li").on("click", "a", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        input.focus(); 

    });







});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the code being chaotic :-)
Anyway, change 'Relevant Section' to (Notice the addition of `class` attributes):

```
/*Relevant Section*/     
$('<li>' + '<a class="O">' + 'O' + '</a>' + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + '<span>' + inputVal + '</span>' + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + '<a class="X">' + 'X' + '</a></li>').hide().appendTo(ul).slideToggle(270);
```

Then in 'Other Relevant Section':

```
/*Other Relevant Section*/
ul.on('click', 'a.X', function (e) {
```

and another for O:

```
ul.on('click', 'a.O', function (e) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with this solution and the code is now working as desired! =) I appreciate all the answers that were contributed, thank you so much all.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a class to each anchor and then reference that in jQuery.

```
$('a.oLink').click(function(){
});

$('a.xLink').click(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`contains`**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to differentiate:

```
ul.on('click', 'a:contains("X")', function (e) {
  ...
}

ul.on('click', 'a:contains("O")', function (e) {
  ...
}
```